# App Store sometimes can't install, iCloud icon instead of INSTALL icon

Tags: iphone, applications, icloud, icon

App Store sometimes can't install apps, iCloud icon appearing instead of INSTALL icon, as in the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of App Store showing iCloud icon instead of INSTALL icon]

Please tell me how to make the INSTALL icon appear again for these apps, instead of the iCloud icon? It usually appears for some apps that I've uninstalled before and I want to install again.

Nb. I have forgotten my iCloud password, but i can use the iPhone that do not use iCloud normally.

Answer (score 2):

The cloud symbol means that the app is associated with your account and has been previously installed using your Apple ID (on any of your devices). If you tap on it the app should start to download to your phone.

You may be prompted for your Apple ID password though. If so, without the password you'd be unable to install apps whether they are associated your account already or not.

If so you can go to the link below to try to recover your Apple ID password.

http://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: so if i change my apple id, the INSTALL icon will appearing again on those apps?, anyone already tried?.
i am forgot my email password too, so currently i cant use the icloud

Comment: Yes. If you log into the App Store with a different account then (assuming that account hasn't already been used to download that particular app) then you will see the INSTALL icon instead of the iCloud icon.