# App Store won't install apps I'm trying to re-download, I see the iCloud icon instead of INSTALL icon

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore

Once I've deleted an app from my iPad, I only see the iCloud icon with a down arrow rather than the "Install" button.  When I click on the iCloud icon, nothing happens. I've looked at [App Store sometimes can't install, iCloud icon instead of INSTALL icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143659/app-store-sometimes-cant-install-icloud-icon-instead-of-install-icon?rq=1), but I know my iCloud and App Store passwords and they've been updated in my settings, but I never get asked for any password.  On rare occasion, when I click on the iCloud icon I see the timer circle that indicates something is downloading but it goes away in a second and the iCloud icon returns.

I have no problem downloading new apps, but ones I've deleted I can't re-download. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try to logout and in again by going to the feature page > scroll down untill you see your logged in e-mail account > logout and login again and try again.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Unfortunately both instructions were unable to fix. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the cloud/arrow button **is** the install button. You are missing buttons to acquire the app and add it to your account (either GET or PURCHASE).

Try signing out of your iTunes Store account, restarting your phone (power off and on), and sign back into your iTunes Store account. That cloud button should still appear and allow you to add the app to your phone (it should turn into a loading spinner, and then an OPEN button).

Answer (score 0):

First reset the cache from the AppStore by opening the app and tapping any single icon 12 times at the bottom of the screen.

Next, from the home screen, tap on `Settings` then navigate down to `iTunes & App Store`. Click on your userID *(email address)* and then click on `Sign Out`.

Restart your phone and head back to the same screen and sign-in using your AppleID. This should rectify the problem for you.

**EDIT:** Below is a picture of what I am talking about when I say *"...and tapping any single icon 12 times..."*

[image: AppStore iCons]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you clarify a bit more as in tap any icon 12 times? When I click on it once it ask for password, so can you clarify how to clear cache of store.

Comment: @Mark I have added an image to the description of what I am talking about